# Adb: ignore offline devices?

Tags: android, adb

When multiple android devices are attached, but only one of them is in debug mode, `adb install|shell|...` will fail with

```
error: more than one device/emulator
```

Obviously, that issue can be fixed by specifying the serial of the online device, either via `ANDROID_SERIAL` or a `-s` parameter. For fixed build scripts under version control, it would imho be better to just use the *only possible* device if there is only one.

**Why does `adb` take offline devices into account?** Is there a way to change that behavior?

---

Note: I'm searching for pure adb answers; I'm aware that I can script a call to `adb devices` extracting the serial of the only device, if any. But it just feels wrong for such a simple issue...

Comment: as someone who was involved with android development and automated testing since Android 1.5 I can tell you that `adb` works just fine as it is. I am not saying it can't be improved. But the issues you are blaming on `adb` can be solved with proper configuration of your system environment. I have not seen an `adb` device going offline for a few years now.

Comment: @AlexP. Hm, maybe my devices are defect/weird, then? At least for me, an android device which is plugged in (charging or MTP) is listed as offline if debugging is disabled on the device. It happens quite frequently that I need to charge my personal device while developing on a separate one; in that case I need to explicitly specify the serial on each build (or automate that through the IDE I'm working in, if any). I wondered if there is a simpler solution than that, or if there is a reason adb acts the way it does. I did not intend to 'blame' `adb` for anything.